# How can I preallocate a non-numeric vector in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct, pre-allocation

I've often found myself doing something like this:

```
unprocessedData = fetchData();  % returns a vector of structs or objects
processedData = [];             % will be full of structs or objects

for dataIdx = 1 : length(unprocessedData) 
    processedDatum = process(unprocessedData(dataIdx));
    processedData = [processedData; processedDatum];
end
```

Which, whilst functional, isn't optimal - the `processedData` vector is growing inside the loop. Even `mlint` warns me that I should consider preallocating for speed.

Were data a vector of `int8`, I could do this:

```
% preallocate processed data array to prevent growth in loop
processedData = zeros(length(unprocessedData), 1, 'int8');
```

and modify the loop to fill vector slots rather than concatenate.

**is there a way to preallocate a vector so that it can subsequently hold structs or objects?**

---

**Update:** inspired by [Azim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591495/matlab-preallocate-a-non-numeric-vector/591569#591569), I've simply reversed the loop order. Processing the last element first forces preallocation of the entire vector in the first hit, as the debugger confirms:

```
unprocessedData = fetchData();

% note that processedData isn't declared outside the loop - this breaks 
% it if it'll later hold non-numeric data. Instead we exploit matlab's 
% odd scope rules which mean that processedData will outlive the loop
% inside which it is first referenced: 

for dataIdx = length(unprocessedData) : -1 : 1 
    processedData(dataIdx) = process(unprocessedData(dataIdx));
end
```

**This requires that any objects returned by `process()` have a valid zero-args constructor** since MATLAB initialises `processedData` on the first write to it with real objects.

`mlint` still complains about possible array growth, but I think that's because it can't recognise the reversed loop iteration...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know the fields of the structure `processedData` and you know its length, one way would be the following:

```
unprocessedData = fetchData();
processedData = struct('field1', [], ...
                       'field2', []) % create the processed data struct
processedData(length(unprocessedData)) = processedData(1); % create an array with the required length
for dataIdx = 1:length(unprocessedData)
    processedData(dataIdx) = process(unprocessedData(dataIdx));
end
```

This assumes that the `process` function returns a struct with the same fields as `processedData`.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [Azim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/591569/52738), another way to do this is using [`repmat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html):

```
% Make a single structure element:
processedData = struct('field1',[],'field2',[]);
% Make an object:
processedData = object_constructor(...);
% Replicate data:
processedData = repmat(processedData,1,nElements);
```

where `nElements` is the number of elements you will have in the structure or object array.

BEWARE: If the object you are making is derived from the [handle class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/handle-classes.html), you won't be replicating the object itself, just handle references to it. Depending on your implementation, you might have to call the object constructor method `nElements` times.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass in a cell array to `struct` of the appropriate size:

```
processedData = struct('field1', cell(nElements, 1), 'field2', []);
```

This will make a structure array that is the same size as the cell array.

Comment: +1 This is a good alternative for making structure arrays, especially if you already have cell arrays of data you want to fill the fields with.