# Memory-efficient way to truncate large array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, memory, truncate

I have a large (multi-GB) array in Matlab, that I want to truncate¹.  Naively, I thought that truncating can't need much memory, but then I realised that it probably can:

```
>> Z = zeros(628000000, 1, 'single');
>> Z(364000000:end) = [];
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
```

Unless Matlab does some clever optimisations, before truncating `Z`, this code actually *creates* an array (of type double!) `364000000:628000000`.  I don't need this array, so I can do instead:

```
>> Z = Z(1:363999999);
```

In this case, the second example works, and is fine for my purpose.  But *why* does it work?  If `Z(364000000:end) = 0` fails due to the memory needed for the intermediate array `364000000:628000000`, then why does not `Z = Z(1:363999999)` fail due to the memory needed for the intermediate array `1:363999999`, that is *larger*?  Of course, I don't *need* this intermediate array, and would be happy with either a solution that truncates my array without having any intermediate array, or, failing that, if Matlab optimises a particular method.

- Is there any way to truncate an array without creating an intermediate indexing array?
- If not, is either of the aforementioned methods more memory-efficient than the other (it appears ot is)?  If so, why?  Does Matlab *really* create intermediate arrays in both examples?

---

<sup>¹Reason: I'm processing data but don't know how much to preallocate.  I make an educated guess, often I'm allocating too much.  I choose chunk size based on available memory, because splitting in fewer chunks means faster code.  So I want to avoid any needless memory usage.  See also [this post on allocating by chunk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549094/974555).</sup>

Comment: Some good questions here.  However, it may no longer be necessary to allocate in chunks, as [it seems likely that MATLAB does this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19061025/2778484) already in recent versions, although details from MathWorks are sparse.

Comment: @chappjc Ah, interesting.  I was not aware that this had changed.  However, there may still be cases where one would want to truncate a large array.

Comment: Agreed.  I was just trying to profile your example with `profile('-memory','on');` when I crashed my computer!

Comment: here's an interesting thread on that matter http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/253015

Comment: Without having any sources, I'm pretty sure that Matlab does those clever optimizations, and your second command does not generate an intermediate array.

Comment: @natan Interesting.  It appears the most efficient way would be a mex-function, also considering three more linked threads [1](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/245581#631580), [2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/241591), [3](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/238109).  Apparently, the "out of memory" may not be due to the `364000000:628000000` array, but due to the fact that the entire `Z` is copied, at least in the first case, although I'm not sure if that's true for my 1-D case.

Comment: Plus, my aim is not what's fast, but what's memory-efficient.  Some of the methods proposed in those threads have the *advantage* that they're fast, but the *disadvantage* that it doesn't free up any memory...

Comment: @gerrit - No, that link provided by natan refers to truncating rows, which is _very+ different than a 1D vector.  For that link: "What you have above is truncating rows, which will necessitate data copying."  That makes sense because when truncating rows, the data must remain contiguous in memory so a copy must take place.  This is not the case here.

Comment: I am not sure and don't have access to Matlab to check, but I think [] is shorthand for double.empty and you may be changing the class of Z. Have you tried single.empty instead?

Comment: @DanielE.Shub I quickly tested, and 'Z(N:end) = []` does not appear to change the class.  I didn't know about the `empty` class method though, that's quite nice!  (For future visitors: [Matlab docs on empty](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_oop/creating-object-arrays.html?s_tid=doc_12b#brd4nrh), and see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2594449/974555).)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ran both examples on a machine with 24GB of RAM with `profile('-memory','on');`.  This profiler option will show memory allocated and freed on each line of code.  These are supposed to be gross *not* net amounts. I checked with a simple function that has net 0 free and alloc and it reported the gross amounts. However, it seems likely that builtin commands with no .m code to back them do not give fine-grained memory reporting to the profiler.

I ran a couple tests for the following code:

```
% truncTest.m
N = 628000000;
M = 364000000;

clear Z
Z = zeros(N,1,'single');
Z(M:end) = [];
Z(1) % just because

clear Z
Z = zeros(N,1,'single');
Z = Z(1:M);
Z(1)
```

For what they are worth, the memory profiling results for this `N` and `M` are:

[image]

Well, both lines *look* the same in terms of memory allocated and freed.  Maybe that's not the whole truth.

So, out of curiosity I decreased `M` to `200` (just 200!) without changing `N`, did `profile clear` and reran.  Profiling claims:

[image]

Interestingly, `Z=Z(1:M);` is practically instantaneous now, and `Z(M:end)=[];` is a little faster. Both free about 2.4GB of memory, as expected.

Finally, if we go the other direction and set `M=600000000;`:

[image]

Now even `Z=Z(1:M);` is slow, but about **twice** as fast as `Z(M:end)=[];`.

This suggests:

1. `Z=Z(1:M);` just grabs the indicated elements, stores them in a new buffer or temporary variable, releases the old buffer and assigns the new/temporary to the array `Z`. I was able to make my weaker 4GB machine go from 2.45 seconds to thrashing the page file for 5 minutes just by *increasing* `M` and leaving `N` alone. Definitely prefer this option for small `M/N`, probably in all cases.
2. `Z(M:end)=[];` always rewrites the buffer, and execution time increases with `M` too.  Actually always slower, and seems to increase exponentially, unlike `Z=Z(1:M);`.
3. Memory profiling does not give fine-grained information about these builtin operations and should not be misinterpreted as giving a total of memory freed and allocated over the commands execution, but rather a net change.

**UPDATE 1**: Just for fun I timed the tests at a range of values of `M`:

[image]

Clearly more informative than the profiling.  Both methods are not no-ops, but `Z=Z(1:M);` is fastest, but it can use almost double the memory of `Z` for `M/N` near 1.

**UPDATE 2**:

A relatively unknown `feature` called `mtic` (and `mtoc`) were available in 32-bit Windows prior to R2008b.  I still have it installed on one machine, so I decided to see if that provides any more insight, with the understanding that (a) much has changed since then and (b) it's a completely different memory manager used in 32-bit MATLAB.  Still, I reduced the test size to `N=128000000; M=101000000;` and had a look. First, `feature mtic` for `Z=Z(1:M-1);`

```
>> tic; feature mtic; Z=Z(1:M-1); feature mtoc, toc

ans = 

      TotalAllocated: 808011592
          TotalFreed: 916009628
    LargestAllocated: 403999996
           NumAllocs: 86
            NumFrees: 77
                Peak: 808002024

Elapsed time is 0.951283 seconds.
```

Clearing up, recreating `Z`, the other way:

```
>> tic; feature mtic; Z(M:end) = []; feature mtoc, toc

ans = 

      TotalAllocated: 1428019588
          TotalFreed: 1536018372
    LargestAllocated: 512000000
           NumAllocs: 164
            NumFrees: 157
                Peak: 1320001404

Elapsed time is 4.533953 seconds.
```

In every metric (`TotalAllocated`, `TotalFreed`, `NumAllocs`, etc.), `Z(M:end) = [];` is less efficient than `Z=Z(1:M-1);`.  I expect it is possible to discern what is going on in memory by examining these numbers for these values of `N` and `M`, but we'd be guessing about an old MATLAB

Comment: A very interesting research. So, is there a matlab command that **efficiently** de-allocates part of an array?

Comment: @Shai - I would say the only good answer involves [`mxRealloc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxrealloc.html), `mexMakeMemoryPersistent` and friends to do unsupported in-place array modification, but that's a longer answer.  I think the tests here show these MATLAB expressions are not very efficient except in certain circumstances.

Comment: @Shai - Note that the fast MEX solution identified in this [MATLAB newsreader](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/245581#631580) thread is rather silly from a memory efficiency point of view, since it doesn't actually free up any memory, as pointed out by gerrit.  So it would have to be something more sophisticated... but I have to think that MathWorks can do better than us. :)

Comment: Interesting, and I've learned that I really should always choose `Z = Z(1:M-1);` over `Z(M:end) = [];`.  But the memory issue that I experienced seems not to be identified by the profiler, not even by the *peak memory* column, so it appears we can't really answer my core question, or can we?  And, why is `Z = zeros(N,1,'single');` not shown in the profiler?

Comment: @gerrit - That's correct, the profiler is only useful for peak and freed, and for expressions comprising built-in MALTAB commands it only seems to provide net values.  The peak value seems useless here. The `zeros` line is not shown because  those are only the lines were _most_ of the is spent (note the "All other lines" row).  Scrolling down in the profiler you get a line-by-line summary.

Comment: @chappjc Is allocating a 628000000-element array *and* filling it with zeroes, then, faster than deallocating one (`clear`, which *is* listed in the profiler)?

Comment: @gerrit - I updated the answer again with another analysis that is perhaps more revealing, although for an older MATLAB version. The `clear` vs. initialization thing seems to be an issue of temporal resolution.  I tried timing this again, and now I'm seeing that `clear` is way faster, but on a different MATLAB version... either way, these are minor lines that are both very fast compared to the truncation.

Comment: @chappjc Great job! +1 I just found out about it through your profile

Comment: Your profile led me to this post as well.  +1 for being a MATLAB boss.