# Memory for big array which change its data and size in Matlab (buffer)

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a buffer (not circle buffer) for big arrays like 100x100 with a specified size.

I can't find any good solution on the internet so i am trying do write it by myself.
Here is the code:

In this exa,ple I will be using only small arrays 2x2 and buffer size is 3

```
A = [1 1; 1 1];
B = [2 2; 2 2];
C = [3 3; 3 3];
buffer = [C B A];
D = [4 4; 4 4];
```

Now i want to push D and pop A to look like [D C B]

```
buffer = buffer(1:2,3:6);      %creating [C B]
buffer = [D buffer]            %creating [D C B]
```

Now the question:
What about the A in the memory? Is it still there or it is deleted? 
If I use about 1000 arrays with size [500x500] with buffer size 3 it would be really bad if I had so much trash in memory. If it is wrong, is there any other way to write such buffer?

Comment: With `buffer = [C B A];`, then `buffer = buffer(1:2,3:6);` removes `C`, leaving `buffer` as `[B A]`, is that what you meant or did you want to remove `A` with `buffer = buffer(:,1:4);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "push front" syntax `buffer = [D buffer]` seems fine.

As for "push back", you can either concatenate in a similar manner (`buffer = [buffer D];`) or you can index past the end:

```
buffer(:,end:end+size(D,2)) = D; % assuming size(D,1) equals size(buffer,1)
```

For "pop" you either do `buffer=buffer(keepRows,keepCols);` as in your example, or you can assign `[]` to whatever indexes you want to remove.  For example, given `buffer = [C B A];`, "pop front" to remove `C` would be:

```
buffer(:,1:size(C,2)) = [];
```

You can remove any values this way, including center elements:

```
buffer(:,3:4) = []; % remove B from [C B A]
```

In this way, **`buffer` is rewritten and the removed values are lost. However, the original variable (e.g. `B`) used to compose `buffer` remains until you clear it.** Keep in mind that when you do `buffer = [C B A];`, it **copies** the contents of each variable when doing [horizontal concatenation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html), rather than putting the array in a list.

I once did a [pretty thorough comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19648283/2778484) of array truncation performance with the `v(end-N:end)=[]` syntax and the `v=v(1:N-1)` syntax. Although that is just for a 1D vector, it might be helpful. You may also want to have a look at [this article on automatic array growth performance](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/05/20/more-about-automatic-array-growth-improvements-in-matlab-r2011a/).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a java linked list.

```
import java.util.LinkedList
q=linkedList()
q.add(A);
q.add(B);
q.add(C);
%get top element
o=q.pop();
%insert new
q.add(D);
```

Your code requires to copy the whole buffer content, which will be slow for large buffers.

Comment: Isn't there any matlab(ish) solution ?:)