# Delete rows in a vector starting from a specific index Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an `nx1` vector in Matlab. I want to delete rows starting from a specific `index`. For example, if `n is 100` and the `index is 60` then all rows from 60 till 100 will be removed. I've found this `REMOVEROWS` but I don't know how to make it do this.

Comment: This is pretty basic Matlab, but see [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633192/memory-efficient-way-to-truncate-large-array-in-matlab/19648283#19648283) for discussion on the best way (at the time at least) to do this: `a=rand(100,1);` `a=a(1:59);`

Comment: thanks! could you make this as an answer to mark it as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should the trick:

```
your_vector(index:end) = [];
```

If you want to remove from the end that you can do:

```
your_vector(end-index+1:end) = [];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this may not be the best way to do this if one cares about performance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19648283/2278029

Comment: what if I want the last 60 elements in an array?

Comment: @user1460166 From the end it is: `your_vector(end-index+1:end) = [];`

Answer (score 2):

The [`removerows`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/removerows.html) function is probably overkill for a vector, but here is how it can be used along with the usual linear indexing method:

```
n = 100;
index = 60;
a = rand(n,1); % An n-by-1 column vector
b1 = a(1:index-1)
b2 = removerows(a,'ind',index:n) % Or removerows(a,'ind',index:size(a,1))
```

Note that the `removerows` function is in the Neural Network toolbox and thus not part of core Matlab.