# Efficient way to delete multiple elements from a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

I have looked around for an answer to this but could not see anything relevant.

I am timing some (Matlab) code and there is one part which takes up a large amount of time. I have a vector, V, of integers (that may contain repeats) and I have a much smaller vector, v, contain indices of elements that I wish to delete. I am currently implementing this as:

```
V(v) = [];
```

'V' is something that I am selecting indices from at random and without replacement. 'v' must not contain duplicates.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are the sizes of your matrices?

Comment: can you give a minimal example

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19633192/2586922

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply.

V is a vector of length roughly ~100000, 
v is a vector : length(v) < 10.

Comment: MATLAB is reallocating the array because you are changing its size; rather than deleting elements, consider replacing them with NaN. Also, is this code being executed multiple times in a loop, or is a single instance running slow?