# Storing handles of objects generated by imline in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, properties, line, store, handle

I am trying to store a set of object handles in an array. The objects are a series of lines generated by imline(.). I want to store the handles in order to be able to change the property of a desired line (in this case, position).

I know how to do this - however, when I try to fill a matrix with the handles of lines, an error occurs - MATLAB states that conversion from IMLINE to DOUBLE is not possible. This does not happen with other types of objects. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Here is some pseudocode to clarify:

```
lines=zeros(1,x);    % defining empty storage matrix
for idx=1:x
    line=imline(ax_handl,[x_1 y_1; x_2 y_2])
    set(line,'UserData',idx) % in order to identify independent lines with the number
    lines(idx)=line; % here I try to store a line handle as it's made
end

% now in the function responsible for motion of objects, I assign new position to line

line_num=get(gco,'UserData'); % this relates other objects associated with line number
setPosition(lines(line_num),[a b; c d]);
```

Comment: some code example will help understanding your problem (I have no problem assigning matrix entries with imline handle objects)

Comment: @Adam, could you insert a snippet that demonstrates how you are filling the matrix?

Comment: The code above shows what I try doing in theory.

Comment: @Adam, please see my answer to this question.  It addresses the issue.  You'll need to change the way in which you pre-allocate in order for this to work.  By default, Matlab variables are `double`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to preallocate an array of class in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510427/how-to-preallocate-an-array-of-class-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to fill your matrix with default valued lines in order to create it.  The typical approach to preallocating a matrix of objects of size `N` would be to simply assign an object to the last element in the matrix.

```
M(N,N)=imline(gca,[NaN NaN],[NaN NaN]); %# set non-displayable vals for x and y
```

**NOTE, the line above will not work with `imline`** as it will call the default constructor for each of the other N*N-1 imline objects in the matrix and a call of `imline` with no arguments forces user interaction with the current axis.

My advice (if you are pre-allocating) is to define all the default lines *explicitly* in the matrix:

```
for k=1:N*N
    M(k)=imline(gca,[NaN NaN],[NaN NaN]);
end

%# Reshape (if necessary)
M = reshape(M,[N N]);
```

Alternatively, you could let Matlab fill the array for you.  If you find that you will need this code often, derive a new class from `imline`.  The following example shows the very least that would need to happen. It merely defines a constructor.  This example allows you to pass optional arguments to `imline` as well.  If no arguments are specified, the `imline` object is created with position values as above.

```
classdef myimline<imline
    methods

        function obj = myimline(varargin)
            if isempty(varargin)
                varargin = {gca,[NaN NaN],[NaN NaN]};
            end
            obj = obj@imline(varargin{:});
        end
    end
end
```

Example usage:

```
%# Generate a 100 element array of `imline` objects, 
%# but define the last one explicitly
mat(100)=myimline(gca,[0 1],[0 1]);
```

The last `myimline` object in the array has points specified as in the assignment, but the rest of the elements have the default position values `[NaN NaN]` as above.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. On a related note, does MATLAB have a tool which would optimize creating a matrix of this kind (other than by loop, as we've done here)?

Comment: @Adam, the problem here is merely that the default constructor for `imline` objects is an interactive function.  In most other cases, we could just construct the entire array by assigning an object to the last element.  Here is a [reference](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brd4btr.html).  Note that the typical approach to generating arrays of objects is to use a loop.  If it were me, and I was going to use this alot, I would consider deriving a new class which inherits from `imline` in which I define my own constructor. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be looking into classdef for future use.

Comment: @Adam, I've updated my answer to include how you might derive a new class to achieve the same result.

Comment: I bow to the prowess of @Amro here.  His answer is much cleaner.

Comment: @ephsmith: I cant take all the credit, if you look halfway through the reference page you linked to, you will find it mentioning the `empty` method :) Also as I later found out, this was previously discussed here on SO (thus my vote to close as duplicate)

Comment: @Amro, Point well taken.  I'll make it a point to search answers here more thoroughly before posting.  I really meant what I said respectfully.  Having read the reference, it still hadn't occurred to me to use that approach you posted.  Thanks for the contrib here as I learned something in the process.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `empty` static method to create an empty array of the class type:

```
lines = imline.empty(0,10);
for idx=1:10
    line = imline(gca, sortrows(rand(2,2)));
    set(line,'UserData',idx)
    lines(idx) = line;
end
```

[image]

Comment: very nice and clean.  That didn't occur to me.