# Retaining handle matrix size upon deletion

Tags: matlab, matrix, size, handle

I have created a set of lines in a figure. The line handles occupy a matrix created by `imline.empty(0,x)`. When I delete a certain line (using `delete(.)`), the matrix changes in size. I want to avoid this by filling that particular place in the matrix with empty space (or anything else) in order to keep the data structured, and the matrix the same size. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806344/storing-handles-of-objects-generated-by-imline-in-matlab/6807795#6807795), consider this example:

```
lines = imline.empty(0,10);
for i=1:10
    lines(i) = imline(gca, rand(2,2));
end
```

Now say we want to delete the third and last lines:

#### Before

```
>> whos lines
  Name       Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  lines      1x10               96  imline   

>> lines.isvalid
ans =
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

#### After

```
>> delete( lines([3 end]) )

>> whos lines
  Name       Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  lines      1x10               88  imline     

>> lines.isvalid
ans =
     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
```

So the array stay the same size when `delete`-ing...

If you want to actually remove their entries from the array, try:

```
>> lines(~lines.isvalid) = [];
>> size(lines)
ans =
     1     8
```