# Iterating an empty matrix using a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I always assumed that iterating an empty vector using a `for` loop was the same as not having the loop at all. However, I stumbled upon this strange behavior:

```
for t = []          %// Iterate an empty 0x0 matrix
    1
end
for t = ones(1, 0)  %// Iterate an empty 1x0 matrix
    2
end
for t = ones(0, 1)  %// Iterate an empty 0x1 matrix
    3
end
```

The result is:

```
ans =
    3
```

Does it make sense, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [`for` loop](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html) runs over all columns of its input. Since a 0x1 matrix has one (empty) column, the loop will simply go over that. No exception is mentioned for empty matrices, so here `t` will simply be the empty matrix as seen from:

```
for t = ones(0, 1) %// Iterate over an empty 0x1 matrix
    size(t) % t is a 0x1 matrix
end
```

Is it a bug? Probably not.
Does it make sense? Well, I think I would prefer the loop not to execute if the input is empty, but probably there are advantages to this as well.

At least it is definitely something to be alert of!

Comment: do you mean `for t = t'` ?

Comment: @TryHard My question was edited and someone removed the `v`. I have updated the answer to match.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin - This was something I wasn't aware about, and this makes total sense.  Thanks for this tidbit of information!

Comment: Hi @DennisJaheruddin, would you please accept the answer to mark the question resolved? (Unless, of course, you're expecting other answers...)