# Cell arrays in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I know what a `cell array` is. I just came to the following line:

```
cell_array = cell([], 1);
```

What does that mean? How can we read the above line?

Thanks.

Comment: It's the same as `cell_array = cell(0, 1)` i.e. making a 0x1 empty cell matrix but I can't say I know any reason for doing this. You could for example make a 0x0 cell array like this `cell_array = {}` if you're just initialising for a loop

Comment: @Dan. When you say `0x1`. Does that literally mean `0` rows and `1` column? How can we have `0` rows? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. I don't know why you would need this. 0x0, i.e. empty is useful. 0x1 is pretty much just as empty to me though :/

Comment: An empty cell array lets you have subsequent codes to concatenate to it. Otherwise, the variable does not exist, which produces an error.

Comment: @radarhead so why not just `{}` then or `cell([],[])` or `cell(0,0)`. Why 0x1 instead of 0x0?

Comment: I can think of one. Say the subsequent concatenation wants to check the number of columns to make sure they match before merging them. It's a way to preset the number of columns if you will.

Comment: @radarhead That's a good observation!

Answer (score 2):

So this makes a 0x1 empty cell array. As in literally 0 rows and 1 column. You could make a 0x0 cell array like this:

```
cell_array = {}
```

which makes sense to me. I do that sometimes like if you can't preallocate before a loop, sometimes it's useful to concatenate onto or to go `cell_array(end) = ...` in the loop.

I really don't know why you'd prefer a 0x1 but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950940/iterating-an-empty-matrix-using-a-for-loop) shows how it differs from a 0x0. So I mean, if for some weird reason you are running a for loop on this empty array you know it will run at least once :/ But that's really scraping the barrel for a reason. I think just stick with `= {}`.

**EDIT:**

As @radarhead points out, this is one way to preset the number of columns if you plan on concatenating new rows in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

`cell` is used to allocate a cell array, in this case: `cell_array`.

So an empty cell of size 0x1 is allocated.
However, this is no usefull syntax for cells. For other (custom) objects it can be useful to generate such empty arrays

```
myArray = myObject.empty(0, 1);
```

Comment: You can use `empty` for cell arrays as well: `cell_array = cell.empty(0,1)`.

Comment: But why `(0,1)` and not `(0,0)`?