# Matlab: Behavior of the unique function

Tags: matlab

I'm currently migrating code from R2012a to R2013b.

I noticed that the `unique` function behavior has changed:

R2012a

```
>> size(unique([]))

ans =

     0     0
```

R2013b

```
>> size(unique([]))

ans =

     0     1
```

It seems counter-intuitive to me that a 0x0 matrix would become a 0x1 matrix after removing doublons, which is essentially what the unique function does. Does anybody has a rationale for this?

Comment: This is possibly related: [Iterating an empty matrix using a for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950940/iterating-an-empty-matrix-using-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 7):

The behaviour has changed with R2013a, if you need the old behaviour use:

`size(unique([],'legacy'))`

If you need code for both versions, I would recommend to write some function which calls  `unique(x,'legacy')` for new versions and `unique(x)` for old versions.

btw: same issue with `union`, `intersect`, `setdiff`, `setxor` and `ismember`

Comment: Here are [the release notes](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/release-notes.html), expand all of 2013a and search for `unique`.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I looked through the release notes and couldn't find a mention to it. Am I blind?

Comment: Ok found it under "mathematics". Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this is the reason, but it does come with an advantage.

Now you will see that `unique(M)` gives the same output as `unique(M(:))`, even if `M` is empty.

Example:

```
M = magic(5);
isequal(size(unique(M)), size(unique(M(:)))); 
M = [];
isequal(size(unique(M)), size(unique(M(:))));
```

The latter returns false on old versions of matlab, this may be confusing.