# What situations do we need to use the `empty` method? What benefits does the `empty` method provide?

Tags: matlab, oop, methods, empty-list

The method [empty](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/empty.html) creates an empty array. What situations do we need to use the `empty` method? What benefits does the `empty` method provide? Will it lead to efficiency improvements through [preallocation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html)? Do they have different implications for the user?

Input:

```
A = ColorInRGB.empty(1,0);
B = ColorInRGB1();
```

`A` is 1x0 `ColorInRGB`, `memorysize=0`.
`B` is 1x1 `ColorInRGB`, `memorysize=0`.
[image: workspace]

What's the difference between `A` and `B`? What's the distinction between an empty 1x0 and an empty 1x1? Or is there any distinction between a 5x0 and a 1x1 empty? If there's no difference, why do we use the `empty` method?

ColorInRGB.m

```
classdef ColorInRGB
   properties
      Color (1,3) = [1,0,0];
   end
   methods
      function obj = ColorInRGB(c)
         if nargin > 0
            obj.Color = c;
         end
      end
   end
end
```

ColorInRGB1.m

```
classdef ColorInRGB1
    properties
        Color; % (1,3) = [1,0,0];
    end
    methods
%         function obj = ColorInRGB(c)
%             if nargin > 0
%                 obj.Color = c;
%             end
%         end
    end
end
```

---

2023/08/27 12:59
These two classes are different. My question is, ColorInRGB1() can help me obtain an empty array, so why do we still need an 'empty method'? Once I know the differences between them, I can understand when to use ColorInRGB1() in what scenarios and when to use ColorInRGB.empty(1,0); in others.

Comment: Your stated outputs are wrong, which makes this look more confusing than it is. `ColorInRGB.empty(0,5)` returns a `0x5 ColorInRGB array`, i.e. it has the correct size not `1x0` as you've stated. This is useful when you have multiple variables which should have some consistency in size so you can operate between them or have more validation / more robust expected behaviour for example looping over the non-zero dimension. Also from the docs _This method is useful for creating empty arrays of data types that do not have a special syntax for creating empty arrays, such as [] for double arrays._

Comment: @Wolfie I'm sorry, that was my mistake. The code should be A = ColorInRGB.empty(1,0) instead of A = ColorInRGB.empty(0,5). Thank you for pointing out the error, I have updated the question.

Comment: The biggest difference between `A` and `B` is that they are of a different class. This muddles the question a bit. Other than that, `isempty(A)` is true whereas `isempty(B)` is false.

Comment: @CrisLuengo These two classes are indeed different. My question is, `ColorInRGB1()` can help me obtain an empty array, so why do we still need an `empty` method? Of course, you mentioned that "isempty(A) is true" is a significant difference. But I also want to know if there are any other differences. Once I know the differences between them, I can understand when to use `ColorInRGB1()` in what scenarios and when to use `ColorInRGB.empty(1,0);` in others.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you for your help.memorysize is a column of workspace, showing the memory it occupies. For example, the space occupied by x=['abad''1235''asdf'] is 1x14. I use the Chinese version of matlab, I don't know what is the name of this column in the English version?

Answer (score 0):

`B` is a 1x1 object array whose only field is an empty array. `A` is a 1x0 object, it has no elements.

`B` is not an empty array, but it contains an empty array. `A` is an empty array.

I understand why the distinction is not directly obvious. Both contain no data (this is the “memory size” reported by the workspace explorer and the `whos` command, which doesn’t include the overhead of the object itself). But there are clear differences:

- The `isempty` test is true for `A` but not for `B`.
- We can index into `B`: `B(1)` is valid, `A(1)` is not. `B.Color` is valid, as is the assignment `B.Color = 'foo'`; you can do neither with `A`.

This is exactly the same as the difference between the empty cell array `{}` and the 1x1 cell array `{[]}`, which contains an empty array.

---

If you are curious about why `empty` can create a 1x0 array, as opposed to only a 0x0 array, and why we want empty arrays at all, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7746202/7328782) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64351256/7328782).