# Creating an array of objects efficiently in matlab

Tags: oop, matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to preallocate an array of class in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510427/how-to-preallocate-an-array-of-class-in-matlab)

I have a matlab code that create an array of objects of class X. X receives a single parameters: an integer.

The array of Xs is created from an array of indexes. Today I'm doing something like this:

```
for i=1:length(integer_array)
    integer = integer_array(i);
    cur_x = X(integer)
    x_arr = [x_arr cur_x];
end
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this in Matlab?

Thanks

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2510427/1214731

Comment: @tmpearce: I'd consider that a duplicate.