# Construct an array of objects in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

Say I have defined a class `house` in MATLAB.

How could I construct an array of objects of class `house`, except the naive idea of loops?

Comment: possible duplicate of this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510427/how-to-preallocate-an-array-of-class-in-matlab)

Comment: I think you'll need the loop somewhere. Either in the constructor or where you create the objects. Check out [this](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/creating-object-arrays.html) in the Matlab-documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `houseArray = repmat(house, numHouses, 1)` to create a column array of `house` structures.  Change `1` to something else if you need an n by m structure array.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create an individual object of class `house`, and then use `repmat` to copy that instance into all elements of a larger array.

Another way would be to create an array by assigning an object of class `house` to a later element - for example by saying `myhouses(2,3) = house`. This works in the same way as when you say `mynumbers(2,3) = 2` - you get an array `[0,0,0;0,0,2]`.

When you use that syntax, MATLAB needs to create a default value of `house` (in the same way as it fills the other elements of the numeric array with a default value of zero). To do that, it calls the constructor of `house` with zero input arguments - so you need to implement that constructor in such a way that, when called with zero inputs, it outputs a default instance of `house`.

A third option would be to implement your constructor in such a way that it could accept input arguments specifying the size of an output array, and then directly output an array of objects with that size.