# Array of objects in generable matlab function

Tags: matlab, simulink

In simulink model I have a matlab function block. Inside the function I would like to create an array of objects in a way it is compatible with code generation.

My question is similar to the one answered here: [Construct an array of objects in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477592/construct-an-array-of-objects-in-matlab)

The problem is "compatible with code generation" part.

When I try to do it with `repmat`matlab returns:

> Arrays of objects are not supported for code generation.

When I try to do it with array of objects I see:

> Recursive calls are not allowed. Function 'dummyClass.dummyClass'
>   participated in a recursive call.

Please find below the code I run:

**embedded matlab function**

```
function y = fcn(u)
%#codegen
x = [1 2 3];
% %% repmat way
% aa = dummyClass(x(1));
% aaArray = repmat(aa,1,3);   
%% array of objects
aa = dummyClass(x);

y = u;
```

**class file**

```
classdef dummyClass    
    properties
        value
    end

    methods
        function obj = dummyClass(value)
           %% array of objects
            if nargin~=0
                m = size(value,1);
                n = size(value,2);
                obj(m,n) = dummyClass;
                for i = 1:m
                   for j = 1:n
                      obj(a,b).value = value(a,b);
                   end
                end
            end
% %% repmat
%             obj.value = value;
        end
    end

end
```

Uncomment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of MATLAB R2017a, there's no way to create arrays of objects that is compatible with code generation using MATLAB Coder or Simulink Coder.

As the first error message says, "`arrays of objects are not supported for code generation`" - it's not a problem with any specific way you're attempting to create them, they're just not supported at all.

MathWorks may introduce this feature in a future version, but it's not there right now.