# How to initialize a vector of class handles?

Tags: matlab, object, vector, handle

I have a handle-based class that I need to create a vector of. An easy method of doing this is to dynamically construct the vector in a for loop, but this causes *mlint* to complain about the changing vector size.

```
classdef HandleClass < handle
    ...
end

...

for i = 1:10
    foo(i) = HandleClass();
end
```

I'm suspicious of the resource-hit required to use this method to allocate large arrays of complicated objects.

A [comment in a previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591495/matlab-preallocate-a-non-numeric-vector/591788#591788) described a useful method to create a vector using the **repmat** function. However, @gnovice warned that doing that would create a vector of handles pointing to the same object. I have tested this and it appears to be the case.

**Is there a trick that allows a vector of unique handle objects to be pre-allocated without the use of a *for* loop?**

---

**Solution Summary**

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879726/how-to-initialize-a-vector-of-class-handles/7879959#7879959) presented by [SCFrench](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4928/scfrench) correctly allocates the memory for the creation of a vector of objects. Other solutions will create the vector, but will not allocate the memory.

```
foo(10) = HandleClass();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to preallocate an array of class in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510427/how-to-preallocate-an-array-of-class-in-matlab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foo(10) = HandleClass();
```

This will default fill foo(1) through foo(9).

Note that this only works if HandleClass's constructor works with no input arguments (that is, it can be default-constructed).

Comment: Thanks. This works too, though I prefer @Praetorian's solution as it will let me use non-default constructors.

Comment: When using this, be aware that this actually calls the constructor to initialize `foo(1)` to `foo(9)`. It may only be used when this as no side-effects.

Answer (score 4):

Seems you can do this by a call to the [`empty`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brd4btr.html?#brd4nrh) method that is present in all non-abstract classes.

```
foo = HandleClass.empty(10,0);
for i = 1:10
    foo(i) = HandleClass();
end
```

Comment: This complains about a conversion error: _Conversion to double from HandleClass is not possible._

Comment: This shuts up M-Lint, but it doesn't actually preallocate anything. Try putting a 10000 element empty array into a variable and look at the Bytes column for that variable in the output of whos; it'll be around 100 bytes. Further, try timing this versus my solution (sample code at http://pastebin.com/Wn41Zhq9). I get a 60x speedup using my technique.

Comment: Thanks for doing the extra investigation, @SCFrench. I've changed my accepted answer to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Having a default constructor the accepted answer is fine. Having no default constructor (`HandleClass()`) returns not enough input arguments) the best possibility I see is creating a cell first:

```
foo=cell(1,10);
for ix=1:10
    foo{ix}=HandleClass(ix)
end;
foo=[foo{:}];
```