# setting object properties value for object array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, object, properties

I have created an array of objects and I would like assign a property value in a vector operation without using a for loop. Unfortunately I get an error.

A simplified example of the problem.

```
classdef clsMyClass < handle
   properties 
      dblMyProperty1
   end 
   methods
        function obj = clsMyClass()
        end      
   end
end
```

And when running

```
vecMyArray = clsMyClass.empty(100,0);
vecMyArray(100) = clsMyClass;    
vecMyArray.dblMyProperty1 = 1:100;
```

We get the following error:

**??? Incorrect number of right hand side elements in dot name
assignment.  Missing [] around left hand side is a likely cause.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My two cents: `for` loop is probably your fastest solution. Also the first line of code (`.empty(...)`) doesn't do anything and its effect is immediately replaced by the second line of code.

Comment: Thanks to MATLAB's vectorization, you're doing this "wrong". Consider turning the class "inside-out" - rather than have an array of objects, have a single object whose properties are themselves arrays. See [this treatise on MATLAB and OOP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1745686/238644).

Comment: @DangKhoa, I plan to have only 20 objects which hold multiple large arrays. I would like to call methods of these 20 objects at once and change their properties.

Comment: @Bee, thanks you are right. I added this line, because of reasons explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7879881/903186

Comment: Are you initializing the objects? Why not just set the property with a default inside the class definition?

Comment: @DangKhoa, in this case initialization would not be an option, because I would like to call a few methods, change properties of all objects and call a few other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you're trying to do now. Use [`disperse`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33866) from the MATLAB File Exchange:

```
>> [vecMyArray.dblMyProperty1] = disperse(1:100);
>> vecMyArray(1).dblMyProperty1
ans = 
    1
>> vecMyArray(10).dblMyProperty1
ans = 
    10
```

Comment: I think this will solve my problem. Unfortunately I am using MATLAB Version 7.9.1.705 (R2009b) SP1 and this gives the error: `??? Undefined function or method 'disperse' for input arguments
of type 'double'.` Therefore I can not validate your solution

Comment: This is not a built in function, it's from the MATLAB file exchange. Hit the link to download it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `deal` function for exactly this purpose:

```
[vecMyArray.dblMyProperty1] = deal(1:100);
```

See: http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/whats-the-big-deal.html

---

Edit: No you can't, actually; that'll set them to all be the vector 1:100.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find your answer [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Error_Messages) in "Struct array errors."  Even though this is a class, similar rules apply.

> Unfortunately missing [] is not the cause, since adding them causes more errors. The cause is that you cannot assign the same value to all fields of the same name at once, you must do it one at a time, as in the following code:

So you'll need:

```
for ii=1:100
  vecMyArray(ii).dblMyProperty1 = ii;
end
```

I know it's not satisfying, but I think it at least helps us to definitively understand this error.