# How to assign pointers to an object's property in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, oop, pointers

I want to create a finite element object oriented program. I have a class **Node**. Since the nodes in a finite element mesh (represented by class **Mesh**) are distinct, I created the **Node** class to be a value class. When I instantiate the array of objects from class **Node**, I assign that object array to the nodes property of **Mesh**. I have an **Element** class too, representing a finite element. I also create an object array from this class and assign it to the element property of **Mesh**. It is clear up to now.

Since the finite element nodes also belong to the elements, I want to assign some of the nodes to the appropriate elements. But copying the nodes results in data redundancy, therefore I want to assign pointers to the **Node** objects so that the *localNodes* property of **Element** contains an array of pointers to the specific nodes. How should I modify my classes below to achieve it?

The **Node** class:

```
classdef Node

   properties
      coordinate;
   end

   methods
     % Not interesting for this example
   end

end
```

The **Element** class:

```
classdef Element

   properties
      localNodes; % the object instantiated from the class Element
                  % will store an array of pointers to the
                  % appropriate elements of the object array stored
                  % in Mesh.nodes. How can I assign these pointers
                  % to Element.localNodes?
   end

   methods
     % Not interesting for this example
   end

end
```

The **Mesh** class:

```
classdef Mesh

   properties
      nodes;    % its object will contain an object array of Node
      elements; % its object will contain an object array of Element
   end

   methods
     % Not interesting for this example
   end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, following some discussion here is a starting point how I would solve this:

```
classdef Node < handle

   properties
      coordinate;
   end

   methods
       function obj=Node(id)
           obj.coordinate=id;
       end
   end

end
```

.

```
classdef Mesh < handle

   properties
      nodes;    % its object will contain an object array of Node
      elements; % its object will contain an object array of Element
   end

   methods
       function obj=Mesh(nodes,elements)
           pnodes=cell(1,nodes);
           for idx=1:nodes
               pnodes{idx}=Node(idx);
           end
           obj.nodes=[pnodes{:}];
           pelements=cell(1,numel(elements));
           for idx=1:numel(elements)
               pelements{idx}=Element(obj.nodes(elements{idx}));
           end
           obj.elements=[pelements{:}];
       end
       function non_deleted_nodes=get.nodes(obj)
           %getter to return only not-deleted nodes
           obj.nodes=obj.nodes(arrayfun(@isvalid,(obj.nodes)));
           non_deleted_nodes=obj.nodes;
       end
       function non_deleted_nodes=get.elements(obj)
           %getter to return only not-deleted nodes
           obj.elements=obj.elements(arrayfun(@isvalid,(obj.elements)));
           non_deleted_nodes=obj.elements;
       end

   end

end
```

.

```
classdef Element < handle

   properties
      localNodes; % the object instantiated from the class Element
                  % will store an array of pointers to the
                  % appropriate elements of the object array stored
                  % in Mesh.nodes. How can I assign these pointers
                  % to Element.localNodes?
   end

   methods
       function obj=Element(localNodes)
           obj.localNodes=localNodes;
       end
       function non_deleted_nodes=get.localNodes(obj)
           %getter to return only not-deleted nodes
           obj.localNodes=obj.localNodes(arrayfun(@isvalid,(obj.localNodes)));
           non_deleted_nodes=obj.localNodes
       end
       function delete(obj)
           for ix=1:numel(obj.localNodes)
               %The 1 is not a typo, we will delete always the first
               %element until the list is empty
               obj.localNodes(1).delete();
           end
           delete@handle(obj);
       end
   end

end
```

And finally a short demonstration:

```
m=Mesh(10,{[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]})
m.elements(1).localNodes
m.elements(1).localNodes(1).delete()
%now the node is deleted from the element and the mesh
m.elements(2).delete()
%now element 2 together with the nodes is deleted.
```

Comment: Thank you for your classes. Two questions:
1) Why is `delete@handle(obj);` needed?
2) Correct me if I'm wrong. The **Element** class needs to be a handle class, because if I delete an element, its two nodes must be removed from both the Element object AND the Mesh object. If I wanted to delete just nodes, then it would be enough the **Node** class to be handle class, since in that case I wanted to remove that Node object both from the Element AND the Mesh but the element would remain. Reformulating: which condition demands the **Element** class to be a handle class?
3) See my next comment.

Comment: 3) Can we delete a specific Node or Element object permanently, not just its handle so that the getter methods are not required in **Mesh**? Or in case of a handle class, the object cannot be deleted just its handle?

Comment: Perhaps I have the answer for the first question: if you delete an element, first you delete its nodes in a loop, than the element itself. But why is the command `delete@handle(obj)` needed? When the function exits, it automatically deletes the element, doesn't it? The delete function is just needed to ensure that the nodes are also deleted, right?

Comment: 1) The call is not necessary, I thought it would be required to call `delete` in handle but it is called in any case.

Comment: 3) To permanently remove the references, use `obj.localNodes=obj.localNodes(arrayfun(@isvalid,(obj.localNodes)));` and similar for the other attributes.

Comment: 2) It is possible without using handle, but then you can no longer implement a delete in the `Element` class, you must modify the `Mesh` properties to delete an `Element`

Comment: 2) I understand now. Which one do you recommend (speed, ease of use) to to able to delete an element by removing its reference from **Mesh** or delete right from the object of **Mesh**?
3) Is it necessary to remove the reference permanently? What do you advise?

Comment: 3) I have updated the code, it will now delete references permanently when calling a getter. This prevents unnecessary large data structures.

Comment: 2) Use the version with `handle` otherwise you can not use references to elements.

Comment: All right, thank you for help very much, I learnt a lot from you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the superclass [`handle`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/handle-classes.html) which let's you use references instead of copying the data.

```
x=MyValueClass(); %assume handle not superclass
y=x; %creates a copy
x=MyHandleClass(); %assume handle is superclass
y=x; %creates a reference to the same instance
```

Comment: Don't you need `< handle` in the class definition to create a handle class? Or can you define a handle to a non-handle object?

Comment: Daniel, I know that in that case classdef Node < handle should be used. However, class Node must also function as a value class, because of my reasoning above. How can it be both a value and a handle class?
@AndrasDeak, that's a good idea to define a handle to the non-handle object. But how can I do that?

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Yes, that's exactly what I suggested.

Comment: @ZoltánCsáti: I don't see your problem using `handle`, could you try to further explain it?

Comment: @ZoltánCsáti You can just create a new object of the handle class for each Node, so effectively, you've got a single copy for each Node with the advantage of being able to pass it around more efficiently.

Comment: The problem occurs here:
myMesh = Mesh();
myElemArray = repmat(Element(), 3, 1);
myElemArray = repmat(Node(), 4, 1);
myElemArray = repmat(Element(), 3, 1);
myNodeArray = repmat(Node(), 4, 1);
myNodeArray(1).coordinate = 0;
myNodeArray(2).coordinate = 1;
myNodeArray(3).coordinate = 2;
myNodeArray(4).coordinate = 3;
myMesh.nodes = myNodeArray;

As you can see, all elements of myNodeArray will have the property value coordinate=3. This is not what I want. Therefore, I have to stick to the value class. But if I define the Node class to be a value class, then it cannot serve as a pointer.

Comment: Ahha, so perhaps the problem in the code I attached in my last comment is that repmat copied the reference to the same object and that's why I gave identically 3. But then how can I initialize an array of objects from a handle class so as to avoid them being pointed to the same single object?

Comment: Your understanding of the problem is right, you can not use `repmat`, instead you have to use a for loop or similar.

Comment: This [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879726/how-to-initialize-a-vector-of-class-handles/7879959#7879959) is suitable for preallocation, right?

Comment: I have added an answer to the question, in case you don't have a default constructor.

Comment: Do you think, it is good to create the constructor of class **Node** as
`function obj = Node(nNodes)
if nargin ~= 0
               obj(nNodes) = Node();
end
end`
?

Comment: @ZoltánCsáti: No! This way you create a `Node` object which holds a `Node` object. If you intend to have an array, make `Mesh` being an array which holds nodes. I don't fully understand what a Mesh and an Element is in your context, so I can not really recommend a finished architecture. You may update your question with more details (What structure you actually want to instantiate), then I could give more advice how to implement it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94346/discussion-between-zoltan-csati-and-daniel).