# Initialisation of a struct arrray without knowing the number of fields

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, initialization

I am trying to preallocate an array of structures but without knowing which fields are contained in the structure. Is there a way to preallocate a `1x4 struct` without knowing how much fields it will contain ?

Following many previous questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/591569/11756186) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664090/how-to-initialize-an-array-of-structs-in-matlab) the way to preallocate an array of structure, knowing the fields would be :

```matlab
N = 10;
struct_array = struct('x',cell(1,N),'y',cell(1,N));

for i = 1:N
    a.x = i*i;
    a.y = num2str(i+i);
    struct_array(i) = a;
end
```

Comment: Are you trying to preallocate this array because the editor tells you to 'consider preallocating for speed'? If so, don't bother unless profiling actually shows you it's too slow.

Comment: You can create an array of blank structs then populate the fields in each struct accordingly. The example you provided is not a correctly working one. Can you show us an actual example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @nekomatic Yes I am. Actually by profiling this example preallocating is slower than using the for loop without preallocating. Have you an idea about this behavior ?

Comment: @rayryeng the example is pretty close to what I'm trying to do, the only significant difference in my real code is that a is given as an output of a function.

Comment: If you don't know the outputs, there's likely something a bit janky about the structure of your code. The difficulty in pre-allocation here is an indication that you could be more considerate about how you're handling your data. i.e. if *you* don't know what outputs to expect, how can you expect *MATLAB* to know what outputs to expect?

Comment: Let me rephrase what I mean : I don't want to hardcode the name of the fields in case I choose to change the output of my function a some point. That is why I try to avoid a specific declaration as seen in line 2 of the code given in the question. Does that make more sense ? Note that my structure is known and the number of fields is constant.